# Determinant, invertible matrices, and rank - Help with true/false questions in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm having trouble with some true/false questions in my linear algebra class and was hoping someone could help me out.

Here are the questions:

a) For all square matrices $A$, $\det(2A)=2\det(A)$.

b) For all square matrices $A$, $\det(A^T)=\det(A)$.

c) If a $3\times3$ matrix $A$ is invertible, then $\mathrm{rank}(A)=3$.

d) Assume $A$ is the transformation matrix for reflecting vectors in a given plane through the origin. Then $\det(A)=1$.

e) Let $A$ be a square matrix. If the homogeneous equation system $AX=0$ has a unique solution, then the non-homogeneous equation system $AX=Y$ has a unique solution for all $Y$.

---

I tried to solve them but I'm not sure if I did it right. Here are my attempted solutions:

- a) For all square matrices $A$, $\det(2A)=2\det(A)$.

Solution: **True**. This can be proven using the properties of determinants, specifically that $\det(kA)=k^n*\det(A)$, where $k$ is a scalar and $n$ is the dimension of $A$. Since $A$ is square, it has the same number of rows and columns, which means $n$ is the same for $A$ and $2A$. Therefore, $\det(2A)=2^n*\det(A)=2\det(A)$.

- b) For all square matrices $A$, $\det(A^T)=\det(A)$.

Solution: **True**. This is a well-known property of determinants, that the determinant of a matrix is the same as the determinant of its transpose.

- c) If a $3\times3$ matrix $A$ is invertible, then $\mathrm{rank}(A)=3$.

Solution: **True**. An invertible matrix is one that has a unique solution to the equation $Ax=b$ for any non-zero $b$. Since $A$ is $3\times3$, its rank is at most $3$. If $A$ is invertible, then its rank must be exactly $3$, since otherwise the equation $Ax=0$ would have non-zero solutions, which contradicts the invertibility of $A$.

- d) Assume $A$ is the transformation matrix for reflecting vectors in a given plane through the origin. Then $\det(A)=1$.

Solution: **False**. The transformation matrix for reflecting vectors in a given plane through the origin is actually $-I$ or $I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix. Both of these matrices have determinant $-1$ or $1$, respectively, so $\det(A)$ cannot be $1$.

- e) Let $A$ be a square matrix. If the homogeneous equation system $AX=0$ has a unique solution, then the non-homogeneous equation system $AX=Y$ has a unique solution for all $Y$.

Solution: **True**. If the homogeneous equation system $AX=0$ has a unique solution, then the only solution is the trivial one, $X=0$. Since the non-homogeneous equation system $AX=Y$ is equivalent to the equation $AX-Y=0$, this means that $AX=Y$ has a unique solution for any $Y$, since the only solution to $AX-Y=0$ is $X=0$, which implies that $AX=Y$ has a unique solution given by $X=0+Y=Y$.

---

Can someone please tell me if my answers are correct and if not, where I went wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Regarding a), $2^n\ne2$ unless $n=1$

Answer (score 0):

a)
False, because $2^n\neq 2$ unless $n=1$.

b)
True

c)
True

d)
False, but your reasoning is incorrect.
First, $I$ does not reflect vectors about a plane through the origin,
it is the identity and it does nothing.
Also, $-I$ does not reflect vectors about a plane through the origin if $n>1$, although it reflects vectors about the origin.
To disprove the statement,
the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
reflects vectors about the $yz$-plane,
but has determinant $-1$.

e)
True, but your reasoning is incorrect.
You seem to think that $X=0$ is a solution to $AX-Y=0$ for any $Y$.
That is simply not true if $Y\neq 0$.
Just plug in $X=0$ and see what happens.
The correct way to argue is to note that $AX=0$ having a unique solution
implies that the null space of $A$ is trivial,
so $A$ is invertible.
Then $X=A^{-1}Y$ is a solution to $AX=Y$.
To show uniqueness,
note that if $Z$ is another solution, i.e. $AZ=Y$,
then we have $Z=A^{-1}Y$ by left multiplying $A^{-1}$ on both sides.
This shows that any solution is equal to $A^{-1}Y$,
proving the uniqueness.

Comment: $-I$ shouldn’t be a reflection, as any reflection can be written in a suitable basis as the diagonal matrix with all $1$’s and one $-1$.

Comment: @Chris If I'm not mistaken, reflection through the origin is simply the map $v\mapsto -v$, which can be represented by $-I$. It's not a reflection about a line or hyperplane.

Comment: It says in the problem statement reflection in a given plane, perhaps we interpreted that differently.

Comment: @Chris I see. It does make more sense to interpret the statement as reflection about a plane that passes through the origin.